# Are there any chromosomal/molecular difference in following human reproductive- traits?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, human-genetics, terminology

Are there any chromosomal/molecular difference in 5 following human traits?Klinefelter-syndrome, Transgender, Bisexual, intersex, hermaphrodite. Are all 5 terms **synonymous**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..
Strictly speaking...
They are not the same.
Each of them has actually a different meaning and some of them such as hermaphrodite is used for lower animals while bisexual for plants animals etc.
Klinefelter's syndrome is totally different and has got nothing to do with the normal bisexual conditions.

Yeah...
sometimes we can use these words interchangeably.

Comment: +1'd and Accepted for "Each of them has actually a different meaning"